# Status of git clone running in background in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, git-clone

I just initiated git clone from Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. The repo is quite large so I clicked "Continue in Background" so the progress window went away. But now I am not seeing anything in the UI indicating the status of the operation. How do I monitor/pause/resume/abort a git clone running in the background in Visual Studio 2019 community edition?

Edit: I can see the progress in the Output Window if I select "Source Control - Git" under "Show output from:".

Answer (score 4):

You can get even better information with a progress bar if you click the 'Background tasks' button in the bottom-left corner (the image is from Visual Studio Community 2022).

[image: Visual studio background tasks]